# Automatically testing for typical edge cases?

Tags: unit-tests, gui, input-field, string

I want to set up automated testing on my UI components. For anything that renders textual data (i.e. strings or numbers), I would like to automatically test for typical edge cases, such as:

- Very long strings
- Empty strings
- 0
- -1, 1
- min/max values
- null/undefined
- etc.

Is there an existing framework/library/tool that supports this?

Comment: Not answer because I don't know if it exist, but ML/AI based tools should do this best- the trick is not only knowing the list of edge cases but also when and where to apply them.

Answer (score 4):

You can refer to the [Big List of Naughty Strings](https://github.com/minimaxir/big-list-of-naughty-strings) to supply data for these scenarios.

The list itself is in [this file](https://github.com/minimaxir/big-list-of-naughty-strings/blob/master/blns.txt).

[image]